# How would "is that what's supposed to look like" sound to you?

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-construction, sentence-usage

Consider you are asked to deliver your answer in an exam in form of a graph. Now, you want to make sure if you are right or wrong when you handing in the paper. I would say

> Is that what's supposed to look like?

I searched the google for this phrase, but the number of results is not very high or conclusive. I know it's not a good idea to use google search for such a long phrase, but it just made me wonder if something is wrong with this sentence.

I know the most common way of conveying that is to say

> Is it supposed to look like that?

However, I am wondering how would the first highlighted sentence above sound to a native english speaker? Also, is there anything obvious that makes it ungrammatical or idiomatic? Or it's just unidiomatic (if it is!)

Comment: Try "Is that what it's supposed to look like?" Perfectly idiomatic English.

Comment: @Robusto Oh, OK, I see now, a subject is required there! That makes a lot of sense! Thanks, that's a bit tricky though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, let's start with a declarative main clause:

> *It's* supposed to look like **this**.

We'll turn it into a question by replacing *this* with *what*:

> *It's* supposed to look like **what**?

But this sort of question is only allowed under special circumstances – for example, if you couldn't hear what someone said, or if you wanted to express incredulity at what they said.

Let's turn it into a normal question instead (an interrogative clause):

> **What** *is it* supposed to look like ＿＿＿?

We did two things here:

1. We moved *what* to the front of the sentence, leaving behind a gap, which I've marked using an underline.  Normally the gap would not be written down.
2. We inverted the subject *it* with the auxiliary *is*.

We had to do step #2 because this was a main clause; main clause interrogatives are marked by subject–auxiliary inversion, unless the *wh*-phrase is part of the subject.

In your example, we have the same thing, except it's a subordinate clause:

> Is that [ **what** *it's* supposed to look like ＿＿＿ ] ?

Subordinate interrogatives are **not** marked by subject–auxiliary inversion, so the only thing we need to do here is move *what* to the front.  The subject and auxiliary remain in their original order: *it's*, not *is it*.

Your version is the same thing, but it omits the subject *it*:

> *Is that [ **what** *∅'s* supposed to look like ＿＿＿ ] ?

Here, the ∅ symbol indicates that something has been left out.  However, there is nothing that would allow you to omit the subject here, so your example is ungrammatical.

---

In this answer, the * symbol indicates that a sentence is ungrammatical.

Comment: Thanks Snailboat, seconds after @Robusto 's comment, the discussion I had with you long time ago on the main chat room flashed on my mind. Thanks again for leaving the answer.